# Liferay JSP Hook: issues when trying to customize login.jsp

Tags: jsp, liferay, hook, portlet

I am trying to override login page to add additional content in the bottom. I referred to [this post](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/jsp-include-buffer) and created the following test code in Liferay development studio (liferay EE 6.1.2 with Tomcat bundle).

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>

<liferay-util:buffer var="html">
    <liferay-util:include
        page="/html/portlet/login/login.jsp"
        useCustomPage="<%= false %>"
    />
</liferay-util:buffer>

<div style="border: 4px solid red; padding: 4px;">
    <%= html %>
</div>
```

After deployed, I saw many nested red rectangles in login portlet. Nothing else.

I tried to remove the liferay-util:buffer to just include the login page, and I got a stack overflow error.

Please advise if I did anything wrong.

Thanks,
Fan

Comment: write "strict=true" after "useCustomPage" and see that solves your problem or not

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried add strict=true. No changes to the output page

Comment: <liferay-util:buffer var="html">
    <liferay-util:include
        page="/html/portlet/login/login.jsp"
        useCustomPage="<%= false %>"
        strict="<%=true%>"
    />
</liferay-util:buffer>
you wrote this?

Comment: yes. The porlet still nested with rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including login.jsp inside login.jsp which is creating infinite loop, hence you are getting too many red rectangles.

Instead of login.jsp, use login.portal.jsp as per the post you mentioned in question.

Comment: @Pankaj Good observation. How I missed that ;)